# How to get full circle instead of getting a major sector of it down here?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to contour plot pressure at a given height (z=34) where I already have the 3D pressure data (P, varying with r & z, independent of theta).

I am using the following command for doing so, but a sector of the the circle doesn't appear.

```
n=50;
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,n-6);
r = linspace(0.01,5,n+1);
[R,th] = meshgrid(r(2:n-5),theta);
[x1,y1] = pol2cart(R,th);
contour(x1,y1,P(:,:,34))
```

What shall I do to make it full circle?
  [image]

Comment: You need to give a minimum complete example of the code. What is `n` and `P`?

Comment: you sure it is not a problem of your data? i put random values for P and the code seems to work

Comment: @shamalaia, the code works but the plot is an incomplete circle, missing a sector. Also defining P by rand(n-6,n-6,n-6) gives the same part of circle missing a sector, which means there's no problem with the data.

Comment: @learnvst , n=50 and you can take P as any (n-6,n-6,n-6) matrix. for instance, take P=rand(n-6,n-6,n-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours call to function `pol2cart` passes the arguments in the wrong order. `th` should be the first argument. So try:

```
[x1,y1] = pol2cart(th, R);
```

Comment: it worked but my data (which should not vary in theta direction) varies in theta direction too.

Comment: @uditsrivastava: Post a sample of your data and explain why the plot is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: here is the sample code:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-rqPMNkwWbNbGpFV015SHlhTWs

Comment: If you append this at the end of the code, do you get the plot you expected? `r = linspace(0.01,5,n+1);
[th, R] = meshgrid(theta, r);
[x1,y1] = pol2cart(th,R);
contour(x1,y1,P(:,:,1))
` Note that the order of the arguments in `meshgrid` is opposite of what you originally had.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
[x1,y1] = pol2cart(R,th);
```

with

```
x1 = R.*cos(th);
y1 = R.*sin(th);
```

Comment: How did they get worse? This produces a full circle for me.

Comment: this is what I got-
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_w_ZJMBaP8UaW4xNFR6enBFNUk